# How to add print port monitor driver in Windows 2012 R2 Core?

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2012-r2, server-core

I have a print port monitor driver (inf & dll files) I'd like to install on Windows Server 2012 R2 Core.

On a full server with desktop environment, I do it by running printui.exe /s, select ports tab, add port and then new port type.

However, on Windows 2012 R2 Core `printui.exe /s` just returns without showing print server properties.

Here is what I have installed:

```
PS C:\Users\justin> Get-WindowsFeature *print*

Display Name                                            Name
------------                                            ----
[X] Print and Document Services                         Print-Services
    [X] Print Server                                    Print-Server
    [ ] Distributed Scan Server                         Print-Scan-Server
    [ ] Internet Printing                               Print-Internet
    [ ] LPD Service                                     Print-LPD-Service
```

Is there another required component for `printui.exe` to display print server properties?

Is there a way to do it by command line? I looked at scripts under C:\windows\System32\Printing_Admin_Scripts\, none of them seems related to my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`pnputil`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff800798.aspx) for managing drivers from the commandline ([source](http://syrewiczeit.com/installing-3rd-party-drivers-on-a-windows-server-2012-r2-server-core-box/)).

```
pnputil.exe -i -a "C:\path\to\your.inf"
```

Comment: Thanks. I successfully installed the driver. But I can't configure the port and enable printer pooling without accessing the "print server properties" and "printer properties". I guess there are some GUI related DLL missing on Windows Core, but I just can't figure out what they are.

Comment: Then using Server Core might not be an option.

Comment: Not doable in Core environment. Confirmed by MS https://support.microsoft.com/ja-jp/help/2750444 -- the article is in Japanese, I used chrome to translate it and got the basic idea.